# how to find which rows are related by mathematical difference of x in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

i have a data frame with about 20k IDs of chemical compounds and the corresponding molecular weights, something like this:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
MASS <- c(324,162,508,675,670)
d <- data.frame(ID, MASS)

  ID MASS
1  1  324
2  2  162
3  3  508
4  4  675
5  5  670
```

I would like to find a way to loop over the rows of the column MASS to find which masses are related by having a difference (positive or negative) of 162∓0.5. Then I would like to have a new column (d$DIFF) where the IDs that are linked by a MASS difference of 162∓0.5 are reported, while get 0 for those IDs when the condition is not met, in this example it would be something like this:

```
  ID MASS DIFF
1  1  324  1&2
2  2  162  1&2
3  3  508  3&5
4  4  675    0
5  5  670  3&5
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you get to values like "1&2" n row 1? Also please explain if you are comparing the Mass column across rows (i.e. check all combinations of MASS)? Or look at row 4, why is it 0?

Comment: Or do you just want to group your data into bins, i.e. group 1 = 0-162, group 2 = >162-324, group 3 = >324-486 and so on?

Comment: Concerning your first question I thought that if I would get 1 & 2 means that these two IDs are related by 162∓0.5 difference in the MASS column. Basically I would like the script to read each MASS (row) then subtract/add 162∓0.5 and verify if the resulting number is present in the column MASS. If it is, then list in the new column which IDs have this difference, instead of 1&2 in column DIFF for row 1 I could just have 2 and in row 2 have 1. If there is no correspondence just write 0 (since there won't be row ID = 0)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution using `outer`:

```r
d$DIFF <- unlist(lapply(apply(outer(d$MASS, d$MASS, 
                              function(x, y) abs((abs(x - y) - 162)) < 0.5), 1, which),
                        function(x) if(length(x) == 0) 
                                       return("0") 
                                     else 
                                       return(paste(x, collapse = " & "))))
```

This gives the result:

```
d
#>   ID MASS DIFF
#> 1  1  324    2
#> 2  2  162    1
#> 3  3  508    5
#> 4  4  675    0
#> 5  5  670    3
```

Note that in your example data, there is at most a single match to other rows, but if you apply this technique to your real data you should get multiple hits for some rows separated by "&" as requested.

You should also note that whatever way you do this in your real data, you will have to make approximately 20K * 20K (400 million) comparisons, so it may take some time to complete, and may result in memory issues depending on your set-up.

Comment: I think the TO not only wants to know which row is within the range of +/-162, but also to group the data, i.e. create a new column that would group row 1/2, and 3/5.

Comment: @deschen Perhaps - it's not that clear in the question. The problem with doing that is that there might be two different groups per row. For example, if you had three rows with weights of 300, 462 and 624, then row 1 & 2 would be a group, and row 2 & 3 would be a group. How would you record this in row 2? It would need to belong to both groups, so you could not have a simple grouping structure such as we use in `dplyr::group_by`

Comment: Agree with the bpotential overlap. But I think it's first arranging by value and then it's about when the cumsum from the first to the n-th value is between 161.5 and 162.5, and once it gets larger, a new groups "starts". So 1, 80, 162, 163 would group the first 3 into first group and the last one into a second group.

Comment: @deschen maybe you're right - that's not how I interpreted the question. We'll wait for clarification from the OP.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer you exactly got what I meant even with my clumsy description of the problem.Just 2 minor things: 1) I added ∓0.5 to add some flexibility (so report ID in column DIFF also when MASS differences are 161.5 and 162.5),is it possible to integrate this? 2) indeed I had some memory issue running it on my real dataset, are you aware of any way to run this in a more economical way memory-wise?

Comment: @Elio the solution above should already take care of the +/- 0.5. As for more memory efficiency, you still have to compare all the rows to each other, so you still need to run 400 million comparisons unless you partition the data. One way to do this would be to split the data frame into overlapping pieces according to MASS. Say, take all the rows with values under 1000 and find matches in there, then all the matches between 1000 and 2000, etc. However, you would need to add in matches within [838, 1162] and [1838, 2162] separately, depending on your data.

Comment: @Allan I tried to run your script on the actual dataset I have (kept < 0.5).  I realised that using your script, in the column DIFF the numbers reported refer to the data frame row index instead of the ID column (for instance in column ID are random code numbers that don't linearly increase from 1 to 20k), how could I modify your function to get ID codes rather than index number in column DIFF? Lastly, how should I change your in case I would have to look only for weights that are different by exactly 162 (replacing <0.5 with = 0 gives me an error). Thanks again for your time and support